# How to save lot of object in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() in android

Tags: android

How do I save a lot of objects in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` in android like textview with value and webview with value, and then return the object?

Can anybody provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to save lot of object in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() in android like textview with value and webview with value .

Your example is invalid. Never pass widgets between activity instances yourself, as you will create memory leaks.

For stuff like `WebView`, use fragments, and call `setRetainInstance(true)` on the `WebView`-hosting fragment. Android will then handle all of the details to keep that `WebView` in its fragment alive and attach it to the activity created after a configuration change.

For cases where you have more than one object to return from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, and they will not introduce memory leaks, use a static inner class, or a `java.util` collection class, or something as the container for all those objects, and return the container from `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Comment: ware I have two layout for potrait and landscape with  layout-port and layout-land different design then how to retain state  of webview

Comment: @mohan: Don't change the layout of the individual fragment with the `WebView`. Or, try overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` in the fragment and fixing up your fragment UI in Java code. Or, try `saveState()` and `savePicture()` on `WebView` in conjunction with the fragment's `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
         //((WebView)findViewById(R.id.txtComment)).restoreState(savedInstanceState); } 
   
           commentWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);}