# ImageView causes crash but only when resuming from standby mode

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, standby

I got an Activity class that uses two other classes; one of them extending ImageView and one that extends BaseAdapter like so:
[image: Like so]

My ImageView class does some progresses when it is called and when I am starting it for the first time it does what I want it to. This is also the case if I press home button and then resumes.
But for some reason it does not work if I resume from standby mode. (pressing the button on the phone that makes the screen dark) When I unlock the phone it crashes. It crashes on a nullPointerException, and from what I can read when I try to call getChildAt() on a GridView defined by the BaseAdapter.

Is it any way to make the app do the same as when I press the home button, as when I set the phone in standby mode?
EDIT:

```
public MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass (Context context) {
super (context);
mContext = context;
    MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass someThing =(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass)gridViewIGetTheChildFrom.getChildAt(some int);
```

}
This is what is causing my crash:

```
 11-19 22:00:48.200: E/AndroidRuntime(6252):     at my.package.name.MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass.<init>(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass.java:57)
```

I do not think the code is helping to much and that was why I did not post it in the first place.

Comment: Please post the error trace and the corresponding code

Comment: @fiddler The code is added but it is a more general question to what I can do to avoid crash that only accuors if sleep mode is activated.

Comment: Sorry but I think we don't have enough information to solve the issue... Where is `gridViewIGetTheChildFrom` initialized ? Why is it null ? Where do you instantiate your `MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass `? ...

Comment: Not enough stacktrace and code.. Its actually the code that executes before the line of crash that is the culprit.. so please add minimal supporting code.

Comment: @userSeven7s The MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass someThing =(MyCustomDefinedImageViewClass)gridViewIGetTheChildFrom.getChildAt(some int); is the code that makes it crash. For some reason it does not manage to get my GridView after returning from standby mode.

Comment: Thats coz your view was destroyed. Where does this crashing code exists, which part of lifecycle?

Comment: @userSeven7s it crashes on onPause, but only when the phone goes to sleep and the actual crash accurs while I am rewoke it again.(While unlocking screen)

Comment: Your app only supports landscape mode?

Comment: @userSeven7s Yes, it is a game that is only in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
```

to your manifest file. The crash is a result of activity restart when the lock screen comes up. The lock screen forces portrait orientation and if you are not ready to handle it then your app may crash.

If that doesn't do it, try overriding [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29).

See this post for info on how to retain objects: [How to save lot of object in onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783673/how-to-save-lot-of-object-in-onretainnonconfigurationinstance-in-android)

Also read this [android-group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/Guv6-p4ujrE) for understanding what happens when device goes to sleep.